# how to keep read and write separate mongo replicat set

Tags: mongodb, replication

```
bin>mongod --dbpath "xx"   --port 27017 --replSet replset/127.0.0.1:27018
bin>mongod --dbpath "yy"   --port 27018 --replSet replset/127.0.0.1:27017
bin>mongod --dbpath "zz"   --port 27019 --replSet replset/127.0.0.1:27017
```

client driver how use to separate read/write?
mongodb://host1,host2,host3/

Comment: Please clarify the question, I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: my english is pool ^-^
lost "use"  
 "how to keep read and write separate use mongo replicat set"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, MongoDB always reads from and writes to the primary of a replica set.

Each driver provides a [`slaveOkay`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Querying#Querying-slaveOk%28QueryingSecondaries%29) option that allows you to read from something other than the primary.

You will need to look at the documentation for your specific language to see how `slaveOkay` is used.